# pyspark : Are multiple SQLContexts allowed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm very new to spark. I observed that when I start spark shell with `pyspark` command, I've one `SparkContext` available as `sc`. I'm not allowed to create another one until I stop the running SparkContext. Is it the same case with `SQLContext` and `SparkSession` also ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, We can have more than one SparkSession and SQLContext as well